# Matrix multiplication using EJML

Tags: java, matrix-multiplication, ejml

```
double[][] data_array
SimpleMatrix dataMatrix = new SimpleMatrix(data_array);
SimpleMatrix omegaMatrix = new SimpleMatrix(omega);
SimpleMatrix cMatrix =  dataMatrix.mult(omegaMatrix);
System.out.println("Multiplied");
cMatrix.print();
```

I am using `EJML` library for matrix operation.

```
1.How to convert a simple matrix back to double[][].
```

The above result is a 1 by 1 matrix.

```
2. Can we store this value in a double variable?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is not necessarily stored as a `double[][]` array. In fact, it is stored as a `double[]` array. You can obtain the internal `DenseMatrix64F`, and from this, you can obtain the `double[]` array:

```
double data[] = cMatrix.getMatrix().getData();
```

This array stored the data in **row**-major format.

In order to store this in a single value, you can call

```
double singleValue = cMatrix.getMatrix().getData()[0];
```

---

EDIT: I think this was asked for in the comments, but I'm not sure....:

```
private static double[][] toArray(DenseMatrix64f matrix) 
{
    double array[][] = new double[matrix.getNumRows()][matrix.getNumCols()];
    for (int r=0; r<matrix.getNumRows(); r++)
    { 
        for (int c=0; c<matrix.getNumCols(); c++)
        {
            array[r][c] = matrix.get(r,c);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: How to take value in double array?

Comment: @SreeVeni The question is not clear. If you're asking for `double value = array[i];` you should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: what  i was trying to ask is In JAMA, we can convert the Matrix back to double[][].by using double[][] Inverse = PInverse.getArray();Whether we can go like this in EJML